# Tensorflow: How to convert an integer tensor to the corresponding binary tensor

Tags: tensorflow, binary, int

I would like to convert an integer tensor, `a_dec=tf.constant([2,7], dtype=tf.int32)` to a binary rank-2 tensor such as: `a_bin=tf.constant([[0,1,0],[1,1,1]], dtype=tf.int32)`.

Is there any efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the size `n` of your vector, what about:

```
a_bin = tf.mod(tf.bitwise.right_shift(tf.expand_dims(a_dec,1), tf.range(n)), 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am using TF version 1.4  and it doesn't support tf.bitwise.right_shift() yet. But it is good idea.

Comment: It is available from TF 1.5, and the current release is TF 1.8. Perhaps consider upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution from guik, but failed when converting 1 and 4, like

```
a = tf.constant([1,7], dtype=tf.int32)

b = tf.mod(tf.bitwise.right_shift(tf.expand_dims(a,1), tf.range(3)), 2)
```

Actually, the bits are reversed here, so:

```
b = tf.reverse(b, axis = [-1])
```